# Raspberry pi capture audio without soundcard

Tags: audio-recording, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to record audio via a mic and a raspberry pi, but i dont want to use a soundcard.

I've looked at a electret but you cant hook that up to a pi.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPi doesn't have any audio input as standard, so your choices seem to me to be:

- USB soundcard
- Microphone amplifier and a commercial analogue-to-digital "HAT" for the RPi
- Homebrew solution using a microphone amplifier and an analogue-to-digital converter hooked to a bunch of GPIO pins.

Using a USB soundcard will be cheapest, quickest, and easiest, but has little educational value. The homebrew approach will require significant electronics design and assembly skills. Using a pre-built HAT falls somewhere between the other two approaches.

Comment: The first two options i already looked into. Right now im going to play with a usb mic and record the output directly. 

As for the homebrew i have been looking at these options:
- [electret max4466](https://www.sossolutions.nl/1063-electret-microphone-amplifier-max4466-with-adjustable-gain)
- [mems-microphone](https://www.sossolutions.nl/3421-adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout-sph0645lm4h)
- [spw2430](https://www.sossolutions.nl/2716-adafruit-silicon-mems-microphone-breakout-spw2430)

I was hoping someone had more to go on

Comment: I could suggest an electronic design outline, but my understanding is that this site is for programming questions. The MAX4466 has an analogue output, and the Pi has no analogue input, so you'll need to do some work. Almost every chip manufacturer has a low-cost, audio-frequency analogue-to-digital converter in its range; the ADC080x range provides 8-bit sampling with a direct 8-bit data bus for about £2. The reason there aren't any ready designs for this kind of thing for the Pi is that USB soundcards are dirt cheap.